# Running total / cumulative sum with a target value in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset of companies and the revenue they have achieved in a particular year. I am new to DAX and I need to get a running total measure of those revenues such that the running total does not go beyond a certain target or limit.

```
Year  Ranking  Company name Revenue RT(Target=14)
2022  1        ABC          10      10
2022  2        DEF          9       10
2022  3        GHI          3       13
2023  4        JKL          1       14
2023  5        MNO          1       14
```

Assuming the target below is 14, any time the running total is greater than 14, we maintain the last running total until the total is less than 14.

In the example above: ABC (10) + DEF (9)  = 19, so running total stays at previous 10 on line 2. DEF (now 10) + GHI (3) = 13, so running total is now 13 on line 3. GHI (13) + JKL (1) = 14, so running total is now 14 on line 4. JKL (14) + MNO (1) is 15, so running total stays at 14 on line 5.

This can be achieved with the Excel formula IF(D2+B3 >14,D2, D2+B3). I am able to get the running total in DAX but I'm unable to customise this with a target in mind.

Please help.

I have been able to get the running totals, but I am unable to customise it with as target in mind.

RunningTotal = CALCULATE(sum('Dataset'[Revenue]),
filter(ALLSELECTED('Dataset'[Year], 'Dataset'[Company name], 'Dataset'[Ranking]),
'Dataset'[Ranking] <= max('Dataset'[Ranking])
))

Comment: Re "*I have been able to get the running totals*", can you share your current DAX to that end? I don't see any index or date column, for example, in your posted dataset that could be used as a basis for generating a running total.

Comment: @JosWoolley, I've just updated the above to include how I am achieving the running total at the moment.

Comment: Suggest you re-post your example dataset so as to include some of the columns you are using in your current measure, e.g. Year, Ranking.

Comment: @JosWoolley, I've updated the table above. Any help with be very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm afraid I don't know if that's possible in DAX, since you're effectively asking for a recursive measure.